# Makefiles. multiple rules match a target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using the gnu make and I have the same problem reported in [when multiple pattern rules match a target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455182/when-multiple-pattern-rules-match-a-target). Basically two rules, a generic one, and a more specific one, match the same target but the more generic one gets executed!!. I would like the more specific one to be executed ONLY. The answer given on the above thread is basically to upgrade to gnu make 3.82. I have version 3.81 and it is the one found very commonly with many Linux distributions.

Is there a fix for this problem that would work with gnu make version 3.81?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Both* are executed? I'm using 2.81 and I can't reproduce your result (I get only the first, general rule).

Comment: The accepted answer to the x-ref'd question states _'In version 3.81 and lower, the selection criterion was different; make would choose the first rule that matched the pattern.'_ (1) Are you sure both are being executed? (2) Can you make sure that the more specific rule is listed first (perhaps by dropping the default rules if it is the default rule that is firing first)?

Comment: @Beta and Jonahan, Thank you for looking into this. You are both right, only the generic one gets executed so I updated the post (I was playing with several examples and I confused the results). Still my question applies, how do I solve this issue using gnu make 3.81?

Answer (score 1):

Put the specific rule above the generic one.

Comment: +1 but would you care to elaborate on how to do that if the generic rule is a `%.o: %.c` (or `%: %.c`) rule from the built-in rules?  I think I know (`make -r` is part of it), but I'm not certain.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, the only was I can get make to execute a more specific rule is to comment out the more general one...