# Force make to use a more specific rule

Tags: makefile

I can't seem to force `make` to use a more specific rule. I'm working with version 3.81, which is [supposed to use the first rule it comes to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11455182/915501), but this doesn't seem to work when the more specific rule has a dependency *that must be constructed with another rule*. Here's the basic picture:

```
#rule for the dependency of the more specific rule
%.bbl: %.tex *.bib
    <build the .bbl file>

#more specific rule
some_prefix%.pdf: some_prefix%.tex some_prefix%.bbl
    <build the .pdf>

#general rule
%.pdf: %.tex
    <build the .pdf>
```

So basically I want `make` to build the pdf with the `.bbl` file if it matches `some_prefix`, otherwise use the more general rule. Unfortunately, unless I remove the dependency on the `.bbl` file, the second rule never gets called.

I seem to be able to get it working by adding a hack to the general rule:

```
%.pdf: %.tex %.hack
    <make the pdf with a more general rule>

%.hack: %.tex
    touch $@
```

This seems to work, and the `.hack` files are deleted automatically, but as the name implies, this is a terrible hack. It seems like there must be some better way to force the use of the specific rule.

How can I force make to use the more specific rule? Putting it first doesn't seem to help.

Comment: That `%.bbl` rule works correctly itself? That is you can run `make some_prefix_something.bbl` when a `some_prefix_something.tex` and random `*.bib` files exist and have it work correctly? What does `make -d` say about what make is doing when it doesn't use your rule the way you expect?

Comment: @EtanReisner, that's interesting: If I make the `.bbl` file first and then make the `.pdf` it works. The `.bbl` file normally gets deleted after make runs, though (which is what I want), so it doesn't work without explicitly making the `.bbl` first.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd expect from my answer below: when the `bbl` files exist then step #5 of the algorithm applies because the prerequisite file already exists.  It's only when the files don't exist yet that make needs to try to use rule chaining to create them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting a very important aspect of the [implicit rule search algorithm](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html): `make` *always* prefers implicit rules which have prerequisites which are explicit targets, over an implicit rule where one of the prerequisite patterns does not match a known target and must be built by rule chaining.  See step #5 in the algorithm, vs. step #6.  This is apart from the normal "first in the makefile" ordering of pattern rules.

If you want to do this you'll have to write the `bbl` rule as a static pattern rule, not a real pattern rule, so that the `bbl` files are explicit targets not implicit targets.

Comment: how would I write the `bbl` rule as a static pattern rule?

Comment: You need a list of the `bbl` files: `BBL_FILES = foo.bbl bar.bbl biz.bbl` then you change the pattern rule intro to `$(BBL_FILES) : %.bbl : %.tex *.bib` (and the rest of the rule).  Now it's a static pattern rule.

Comment: I should point out that static pattern rules aren't the only way to solve this.  You  just need to make these `bbl` files be "known" to make, somehow.  Listing them (explicitly) as targets or prerequisites _anywhere_ in the makefile is good enough.  For example given the above variable assignment you could just write a new rule `make_bbls : $(BBL_FILES)` and that would be sufficient.  You don't need anything to depend on `make_bbls`; just having that rule exist is enough.

Comment: It does seem like these solutions prevent make from deleting the `.bbl` files, though. I can live with that, but it's not optimal.

Comment: Correct.  You can't have both: either the targets are intermediate files and get deleted, but then they can only be created by chaining rules so pattern rules that depend on them will always be the last ones considered, _OR ELSE_ they are explicitly mentioned and are not intermediate files and not deleted, and your rule ordering works.  Actually, you could try keeping the `make_bbls` or static pattern rule, _AND_ explicitly declaring them intermediate with `.INTERMEDIATE: $(BBL_FILES)`.  I'm not sure if that will put you back where you started, or solve your problem.