# How do I get Make to do Second Expansion using two rules with the same target containing %?

Tags: makefile

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
$ tree
.
|-- dir
|   `-- subdir
|       `-- data
`-- makefile
```

where `data` is a file. My `makefile` looks like this:

```
all: dir/analysis

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%/analysis: %/subdir
%/analysis: $(addsuffix /data, $$^)
        @echo TARGET: $@ DEPS: $^
        touch $@
```

When I run `make`, I would expect the result to look like this:

```
TARGET: dir/analysis DEPS: dir/subdir/data dir/subdir
touch dir/analysis
```

Instead, it just reports

```
make: *** No rule to make target `dir/analysis', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

If I change the first rule to `dir/analysis: dir/subdir` then it works as I expected. So I suspect that `make` ignores the first rule and skips straight to the second when the first rule is `%/analysis: %/subdir`. It also works as expected when both rules have `dir/analysis` as their target instead of just the first rule. MadScientists's answer to a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28843002/2680824) seemed to apply to my problem. I tried adding rules like

```
dummy_target: dir/subdir
        mkdir -p dir/subdir
```

and

```
dir/subdir: 
        mkdir -p dir/subdir
```

to the end of `makefile` to try to make the dependency on the first rule an explicit target but this didn't change anything. I'm pretty new to `make`, so I'm probably missing something pretty stupid, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. How do I get the first and second rules to execute in the order they're written? I'm using Make version 3.81 in case that matters.

--EDIT--

If I actually add a command after the first rule, like `@echo RULE 1` then that command executes and not the second one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you understand the makefile:

```
# Original
all: dir/analysis

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%/analysis: %/subdir
%/analysis: $(addsuffix /data, $$^)
        @echo TARGET: $@ DEPS: $^
        touch $@
```

like this:

- By default we make `dir/analysis`
- We request secondary expansion
- We say that *whatever*`/analysis` depends on *whatever*`/subdir`. So
  that makes `dir/subdir` a prerequisite of `dir/analysis`
- We say also that *whatever*`/analysis` depends on the thing we get by
  suffixing `/data` to the prior prerequisites of *whatever*`/analysis`. (Secondary
  expansion of `$$^` gives us the prior prerequisites of the target). And
  since the prior prerequisites of `dir/analysis` are `dir/subdir`, that now
  makes `dir/subdir dir/subdir/data` the new prerequisites of `dir/analysis`.

Hence the output of the recipe ought to be:

```
TARGET: dir/analysis DEPS: dir/subdir/data dir/subdir
touch dir/analysis
```

This understanding is badly wrong. You're confusing and conflating the operation
of pattern rules with the operation or ordinary rules.

If a makefile says, e.g:

```
# A
xx: xa

xx: xb

xx: xc
    touch $@
```

or even:

```
# B
xx: xa

xx: xb

%x: %c
    touch $@
```

then the prerequisites of all the empty rules for the target `xx` are combined
with those of the (one) non-empty rule when `xx` is considered as a target. So
`# A` is equivalent to:

```
xx: xa xb xc
    touch $@
```

and `# B` is equivalent to:

```
xx: xa xb

%x: %c
    touch $@
```

and in both cases the prerequisites of `xx` are `xa xb xc`.

However:

```
%x: %a

%x: %b
    touch $@
```

is *not* equivalent to:

```
%x: %a %b
    touch $@
```

If you ever write an empty *pattern* rule, its effect is simply *to delete
any prior pattern rule with the same target and prerequisite patterns*. And if you
ever write a non-empty pattern rule, you simply *replace*
any prior pattern rule with the same target and prerequisite patterns. See
[10.5.6 Canceling Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html#Canceling-Rules)

So:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%/analysis: %/subdir
%/analysis: $(addsuffix /data, $$^)
    @echo TARGET: $@ DEPS: $^
    touch $@
```

is equivalent to:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%/analysis: $(addsuffix /data, $$^)
    @echo TARGET: $@ DEPS: $^
    touch $@
```

Then when this pattern rule is considered with respect to `dir/analysis`,
there are *no* prior prerequisites: `$^` will expand to the empty string, and
in secondary expansion, so will `$$^`. So finally the recipe is equivalent to:

```
# Residual
%/analysis: /data
    @echo TARGET: $@ DEPS: $^
    touch $@
```

You can satisfy yourself of this by running both of the `# Original` and
`# Residual` makefiles in debug mode (`-d`) and comparing the outputs.

This explains why the outputs in both cases conclude:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'dir/analysis', needed by 'all'. Stop.
```

A pattern rule will only be instantiated to make a target *if doing so offers a way for the target to be made.* Why else select it? Since the prerequisite `/data` does not exist, the pattern rule
is not viable and is discarded. Just as if you tried to `make foo.o` with the makefile:

```
%.o: %c
    touch $@
```

when there is no `foo.c` in the directory.

If you really want to see the output you were expecting, then you can get it from:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: dir/analysis

%/analysis: %/subdir %/subdir/data
    @echo TARGET: $@ DEPS: $^
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f dir/analysis
```

But it is hard to believe that is what you really want to see. This makefile
makes the analysis dependent on the data and also on *the directory where
the data resides*. What can be the point of that?

```
%/analysis: %/subdir/data
```

presumably expresses the desired relationship between the data and the analysis:-

- If the data doesn't exist then the analysis is out of date and cannot be made (till you get some data).
- If the data exists and is older than the analysis then the analysis does not
  need to be made.
- If the data exists and is newer than the analysis then the analysis can and will be
  made.

By making `dir/subdir` an independent prerequisite all that you achieve is to introduce
a requirement to remake the analysis if it becomes older than *the directory in
which the data resides* - regardless of the data. So if, e.g. I run `touch dir/subdir`,
that will require `make` to re-run the analysis, even though the data hasn't changed.

I can make sense of your motivation only by supposing that in
reality you also want `make` to *make the data*, and the directory where it resides, if
they happen not exist when an analysis is required. If that is the situation then
you want a makefile on the lines of:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: dir/analysis

.SECONDARY:

%/subdir:
    mkdir -p $@

%/subdir/data: | %/subdir
    touch $@

%/analysis: %/subdir/data
    @echo TARGET: $@ DEPS: $^
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f dir/analysis dir/subdir/data
```

Here, the pattern rule:

```
%/subdir/data: | %/subdir
```

makes `%/subdir` an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)
of `%/subdir/data`. It means that `/dir/subdir` is *not considered* when determining whether `/dir/subdir/data` needs
to be made, but if it is determined that `/dir/subdir/data` is to be made, then `/dir/subdir` will be made first. This
way, `/dir/subdir` will be created, if it does not exist, when you need it to put the data there, but will have no influence
on whether you need to make the data or the analysis.

The special target `.SECONDARY` is a [technicality](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html). It directs `make` not to automatically delete any subsequent targets
that it deduces to be intermediate artefacts that emerge from chained pattern rules. Without it, in this example `make` 
would deduce that `dir/subdir/data` and `dir/subdir/` are just waste-products of making `dir/analysis` and auto-delete them
at the end.

If you run this makefile initially with no `dir/subdir/data` and no `dir/subdir/` you get:

```
$ make
mkdir -p dir/subdir
touch dir/subdir/data
TARGET: dir/analysis DEPS: dir/subdir/data
touch dir/analysis
```

And subsequently:

```
$ make clean
rm -f dir/analysis dir/subdir/data 
$ make
touch dir/subdir/data
TARGET: dir/analysis DEPS: dir/subdir/data
touch dir/analysis
```

And then:

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
$ touch dir/subdir
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a helpful and extensive answer.  I would upvote you more if I could. This helps me see that I'll need a different strategy for what I'm trying to accomplish. I was about to discuss more about my broader goals and what I was trying to do with Second Expansion in my real system, but I think that would be better suited for a separate question.